# I want to post status update but it show empty?

Tags: php, laravel

Controller in function

```
public function newStatus($id, Post $stat)
{
    post::where('id', $id)->update(['status' => $stat, 'id' => $id]);

    return redirect('/postview')->with('M_status', 'Your Status has been updated!');
}
```

web.php route

```
Route::get('/statusUpdate/{id}/{status}', [AdminsController::class, 'newStatus']);
```

blade

```html
@if ($post->status == 'publish')
    <a href="/statusUpdate/{{$post->id}}/{{$post->status = "publish"}}" class="btn btn-info btn-xs navbar-btn">Draft</a>
@else
    <a href="/statusUpdate/{{$post->id}}/{{$post->status = "draft"}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs navbar-btn">Publish</a>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the blade for this to draft when published and publish when drafted

```html
@if ($post->status == 'publish')
    <a href="/statusUpdate/{{$post->id}}/draft" class="btn btn-info btn-xs navbar-btn">Draft</a>
@else
    <a href="/statusUpdate/{{$post->id}}/publish" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs navbar-btn">Publish</a>
@endif
```

and adapt the controller to

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

///...

public function newStatus(Request $request, $id, $status)
{
    post::where('id', $id)->update(['status' => $status]);

    return redirect('/postview')->with('M_status', 'Your Status has been updated!');
}
```